# Is there a fieldtype in Craft like "Content Elements" or "Bloqs" for ExpressionEngine?

Tags: fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype, content

I have been using EE for over 5 years now, and am just starting to get into Craft (and I love it!).  In my recent EE sites, I've used Content Elements, and it has been a great way to give my clients flexibility in adding content to pages and blog posts, etc.

Is there a similar fieldtype available for Craft? Or is there another simple method to accomplish the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [Matrix](https://craftcms.com/features/matrix) [fieldtype](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields).

Comment: Well I'll be... right there under my nose. Thanks, Brad!

Comment: Popular addons for adding even more functionality to Matrix include SuperTable and Neo

https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable
https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo